# Using variables with setRequestHeader, why won't they work?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

Edit: Problem is solved. For some reason the Base64Encode function was putting a line break in the output string, something I didn't notice until I response.write the output and looked at the source code of the page instead of the compiled page.

---

I'm trying to send JSON to a remote server in order to get back a JSON response (Basically I send them data, they perform calculations based on my data and send back different data). However instead of getting data back the server tells me the request failed authentication.

The Authentication involves sending a base64 encoded string, username, and password combined. These values can change so I'm using variables to pass the information on. This does not work, however if I enter the fully encoded value as a string it does work.

```
Function GetAPdataPost(sSendHTML, sURL)
  dim apHTTP
  dim sHTTPResponse
  dim API_KEY
  dim API_PWD
  dim auth

  API_KEY     = "fred"
  API_PWD     = "barney"
  auth = Base64Encode(API_KEY & ":" & API_PWD)
  Set apHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  apHTTP.Open "POST", sURL, false
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization","Basic ZnJlZDpiYXJuZXk=" '<-- works
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & auth '<-- doesn't work
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", len(sSendHTML)
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Account-Number", "00000004"
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
  apHTTP.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"

  On Error Resume Next
  apHTTP.send sSendHTML

  sHTTPResponse = apHTTP.responseText

  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    GetAPdataPost = sHTTPResponse
  Else
    GetAPdataPost = "Something went wrong: " & Err.Number
  End If
  On Error Goto 0

  Set apHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Using the first line result in a proper response form the server, a valid JSON string with all the required data. The second line results in a JSON string saying "The request failed authentication".

So aside from typing out the Base64 encoded string how do I get a variable to be recognised as a valid string?

I should just note that I have tried surrounding `auth` with double quotes (`""`) and `Chr(34)` to no avail.

Edit: Base64 Encode function.

```
Function Base64Encode(sText)
    Dim oXML, oNode

    Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    Set oNode = oXML.CreateElement("base64")
    oNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
    oNode.nodeTypedValue =Stream_StringToBinary(sText)
    Base64Encode = oNode.text
    Set oNode = Nothing
    Set oXML = Nothing
End Function

Function Stream_StringToBinary(Text)
  Const adTypeText = 2
  Const adTypeBinary = 1

  'Create Stream object
  Dim BinaryStream 'As New Stream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText

  'Specify charset For the source text (unicode) data.
  BinaryStream.CharSet = "us-ascii"

  'Open the stream And write text/string data To the object
  BinaryStream.Open
  BinaryStream.WriteText Text

  'Change stream type To binary
  BinaryStream.Position = 0
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

  'Ignore first two bytes - sign of
  BinaryStream.Position = 0

  'Open the stream And get binary data from the object
  Stream_StringToBinary = BinaryStream.Read

  Set BinaryStream = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: The `Base64Encode()` function should be returning a string already, have you tried outputting what `auth` contains to see if the base64 encoding matches your manually written base64 encoded value? Could you also include the `Base64Encode()` function definition in your code above?

Comment: The encoded string I used in my original post (ZnJlZDpiYXJuZXk=) is generated from that function, just straight copy paste. Actually I should say that is just a sample, obviously I can't share the real keys and pwds but the procedure is exactly te same.

Comment: The conversion from text to binary uses `Charset = "us-ascii"`, what happens if the Classic ASP page is `UTF-8`? You might be encountering an encoding mismatch, you'll have use `Response.Write auth` to see what the variable actually contains.

Comment: Switching to UTF-8 gives a completely different encoding result. However while testing with response write I noticed that the base64_encode was actually putting a line break in, something I didn't notice until looking at the raw source code of the page. Problem is now fixed.

Comment: That is why outputting using `Response.Write()` is a key component when it comes to debugging Classic ASP. Glad you found the issue. Now you've fixed the problem, [leave an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) that you can accept so the question is removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Base64Encode function was putting a line break in the output string, something I didn't notice until I response.write the output and looked at the source code of the page instead of the compiled page.

Always remember to look at the raw data, not just the displayed data (i.e. not like me)